# Rails 3 Engine routes resolve 'match' to the assets path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm so confused. Here is my situation. Recently I split the application I'm currently working on to three Rails Engines. One of the engines is carrying about user management. I'm using devise for that. By default device is using a route called (user_route) to redirect users after they log in, so I defined it in the routes.rb file of the engine.

So, the long story short:

In the routes.rb of the main application I have:

```
mount BackOffice::Engine,    at: '/bo'
```

Than in the routes.rb of the BO Engine I have:

```
match 'user/logged_in' => 'users#logged_in',       as: 'user_root'
```

The whole routes.rb in the engine is:

```
BackOffice::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, {
    class_name: 'BackOffice::Admin',
    module: :devise,
  }

  devise_for :users, {
    class_name: 'BackOffice::User',
    module: :devise,
  }

  resources :admins
  resources :users
  resources :life_promotions

  match ''               => 'life_quotations#index', as: 'life_quotations'
  match 'user/logged_in' => 'users#logged_in',       as: 'user_root'

  root to: 'life_quotations#index'
end
```

And than if I go do like this:

```
module BackOffice
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter lambda { raise user_root_path }
  end
end
```

I see the following result:

```
/assets?action=logged_in&controller=back_office%2Fusers
```

Which is far from 'user/logged_in'. And also it stops me from using the default Devise behavior which is kind of convenient for me. But the most important is that I really can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: What does the whole routes file look like in the engine?

Comment: I added it to the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
```

Needs to be used intead of

```
BackOffice::Engine.routes.draw do
```

in your engine, cause the match you have in your engine routes only exists in the namespace of your engine, rather than the whole application.